# Using a Sylow Counting Argument

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a group of order $$|G|=pq^m$$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes and $q^m<p$.
Show that $$G\cong C_p \rtimes_h Q$$ where $Q$ is a group with $|Q|=q^m$ and $h:Q\rightarrow Aut(C_p)$ is a homomorphism using a Sylow Counting Argument.

I have used Sylow's Theorem to show that there exists a subgroup $Q$ with $|Q|=q^m$ and that there is a subgroup $X$ with $|X|=p$ and so $X\cong C_p$.

I have claimed that $X \lhd G$ but I am not sure whether I'm going about this correctly. If this is the correct approach, how would I prove this and would this allow me to come the correct conclusion?

Comment: You can use Sylow's Theorem to deduce that the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups is $1$, and so $X$ must be the unique such subgroup and hence is normal in $G$.