# Sylow counting to show group is isomorphic to semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let G be a group of order $|G|=pq^m$ where $p, q$ are primes with $q^m<p$.

Use a Sylow counting argument to show that $G\cong C_p \rtimes_h Q$ where $Q$ is a group with $|Q|=q^m$ and $h:Q\rightarrow Aut(C_p)$ is a homomorphism

I've shown that $C_p$ is a normal subgroup in $G$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: $Aut(C_p)$ is not a subgroup of $G$. Did you show the $p$-subgroup is normal?

Comment: My apologies, I misstyped that. I meant to say that $C_p$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Comment: Recall the definition of semidirect product. The group is the product of two subgroups that intersect trivially, one of which is normal.

Comment: Or...use the normality of the Sylow $p$-subgroup to show that sending $q \in Q$ to the inner automorphism induced by $q$ restricted to the $p$-subgroup gives the desired homomorphism $h$.

Comment: This identical to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651016 Presumably it's a homework question.